# Inheriting Generic classes with restricted TypeVar

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Consider a simple pair of generic classes:

```
T = TypeVar("T", str, int)

class Base(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, v: T):
        self.v: T = v

    @property
    def value(self) -> T:
        return self.v

class Child(Base[T]):
    def __init__(self, v: T):
        super().__init__(v)

x = Child(123)
reveal_type(x.value)
```

While using `T = TypeVar("T")` works as expected. The restricted `TypeVar` as shown yields the following errors:

```
error: Argument 1 to "__init__" of "Base" has incompatible type "str"; expected "T"
error: Argument 1 to "__init__" of "Base" has incompatible type "int"; expected "T"
note: Revealed type is 'builtins.int*'
```

Note that `reveal_type` still works.

Another difference, is that the restricted `TypeVar` requires the type annotation for `self.v` assignment whereas the unrestricted does not.

In the full use-case, I actually have `Callable[[Any], T]`, but the issue is the same.

This is with `mypy 0.910` and `Python 3.9.7`.

Comment: Can you please provide the code that actually produces the error? Where are you using the restricted type exactly?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried to clarify. Now the first shown code is the one producing the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounding `T` to an `Union[int,str]` should do the job:

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=Union[str, int])


class Base(Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, v: T):
        self.v: T = v

    @property
    def value(self) -> T:
        return self.v


class Child(Base[T]):

    def __init__(self, v: T):
        super().__init__(v)


x = Child(123)
reveal_type(x.value)
y = Child('a')
reveal_type(y.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen anytime you call `super()` and pass the a generic restricted `TypeVar` argument to any function not just **init**. On those cases, I believe we can ask mypy to leave this poor thing as it is, by including `# type: ignore` in those lines:

```
   ...
   super().__init__(v) # type: ignore
   ...
```

It is not so bad as it seems because type checking will still be done on other lines, differently of what would happen if you remove the `: T` from the parameter on parent function or on the child function (any of those would suffice to suppress complains, but would also stop checking inside those functions as well).

Comment: So in your opinion, is this a bug in mypy?

Comment: Yes, this is a [bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/7362)

Comment: thanks for the link @alex_noname, this answers zulan's question. it was opened more than two years ago